# Add ASP HyperLink in Table HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, grid

I have `<table>` tag in asp page. In `<td>` value, I add `<asp:HyperLink>` tag to navigate to another page. But It doesn't work and only show blank page. How do I resolve this?

Here is my current code:

```
 <table class="TblClass" border="1" runat="server">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="auto-style5">Type ID</th>
                    <th class="auto-style6">Number ID</th>
                    <th>Channel</th>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Summarize</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3" class="auto-style5"><asp:Label ID="LblTypeID" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td rowspan="3" class="auto-style6"><asp:Label ID="LblNumberID" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>Detail Txn</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><asp:HyperLink ID="LblCountTransaction" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("intCount") %>' style="cursor:pointer" NavigateUrl='<%# LinkToDetailTxn(Eval("ID"), 1) %>' target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=1000');return false;"></asp:HyperLink></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right"><asp:Label ID="LblAcumulateTxn" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><asp:HyperLink ID="LblCount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("intCount") %>' style="cursor:pointer" NavigateUrl='<%# LinkToDetailTxn("ID", 1) %>' target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=1000');return false;"></asp:HyperLink></td>
                  </tr>
</table>
```

And this my code behind:

```
Public Function LinkToDetailTxn(ByVal idAs Integer, ByVal category As Integer) As String
    Return "~/User/MyPage_Detail_Txn.aspx?IDCA=" & id& "&category =" & category 
End Function
```